# Error when I am redirecting page

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I am getting an error:

> "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack."

when I am redirecting my page from one to another.

I am using this code:

```
try
{
    Session["objtwitter"] = obj_UserDetSumit;

           Response.Redirect("TwitterLogin.aspx");


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

          lblStatus.Text = "Account Creation Failed, Please Try Again";


    }
```

And I got a solution and I tried also this `Response.Redirect("home.aspx",false);`
It's not throwing an error but it's also not redirecting page.

Comment: Please help me for this problem i didnot get any solution any where.

Answer (score 4):

Try - catch creates a thread around code within it in order to catch exceptions.  When you Redirect you are effectively terminating execution of the thread thus causing an error since execution ended unnaturely (though this is by design).  You should not Redirect from within try-catch and if you do you should use Response.Redirect( "some url", false ); and also specifically catch ThreadAbortException.

Comment: this is not working please suggest another way to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4.aspx

Response.Redirect calls the Response.End, which throws a ThreadAbortException, so you'd want to change your code to:

```
try
{
   Response.Redirect("home.aspx"); 
}
catch(System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
{
   // do nothing
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // do whatever
}
```

Comment: Plus i think you should make use of this over load Response.Redirect(string url, bool endResponse);

Comment: thanks for this but both of this is not working please tell me any another way

Comment: this is not working please suggest another way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you are working with a debug build and not a release build of your project. And second, make sure that you are debugging in mixed mode (both managed and native) so that you can see all of the current call stack.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try moving your Response.Redirect outside of the try catch block like this:

```
try
{
    Session["objtwitter"] = obj_UserDetSumit;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblStatus.Text = "Account Creation Failed, Please Try Again";
    return;
}

Response.Redirect("TwitterLogin.aspx");
```

Most people having this issue [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/817776da-13da-43f5-a189-1727ce4f3b6b) resolved it with calling `Response.Redirect("TwitterLogin.aspx", false);` which doesn't explicitly kill the thread immediately. I'm not sure why this didn't work for you.

I think the issue is having your Response.Redirect inside of a try catch block. Calling `Response.Redirect(url);` calls `Response.End();`, which will throw a `ThreadAbortException`.

*Make sure you're not trying to do any more processing after you do your redirect.*

Using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), you can see that `Response.Redirect(url);` calls `Response.Redirect(url, true);`

Passing true then calls `Response.End();` which looks like this:

```
public void End()
{
    if (this._context.IsInCancellablePeriod)
    {
        InternalSecurityPermissions.ControlThread.Assert();
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort(new HttpApplication.CancelModuleException(false));
    }
    ....
}
```

Even though you don't have a finally in your code snippet, it may be trying to execute the "empty" finally, but can't because the thread is being aborted. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your code these line you won't get an exception in the first place

```
try
{
   Response.Redirect("home.aspx", False); 
   //Directs the thread to finish, bypassing additional processing
   Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // exception logging
}
```

Hope it helps